# \@ symbol on media queries and how is it interpreted

Tags: css, sass

I'm currently learning SASS and I've come across the '\@' symbol on a utility map example as shown below:

```
@each $name, $breakpoint in $breakpoints {
@media(min-width: $breakpoint) {
  **.text-size-#{$size}\@#{$name}** {
    font-size: #{$size}px;
  }
}}
```

which creates font-sizes for various breakpoints and compiles to something like this:

```
...
@media (min-width: 412px) {
  .text-size-12\@small {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .text-size-12\@medium {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  .text-size-12\@large {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
}
...
```

What does the '\@' symbol translate to in this case? Am I correct in assuming these classes will be invoked as `class="text-size-12 small"`?

Comment: It looks like simply an escaped @, that is, for a class with a literal @ in its name: `class="text-size-12@medium"`